# как свернуть кусок кода на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно свернуть часть кода, с которой я больше не работаю, но она занимает много места. Свернуть, имеется ввиду как, например, тело цикла или условного оператора.

Comment: Я не могу оставлять комментарии, но я могу вам помочь. В какой IDE, вы работаете? Ответьте в коментариях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, поместите часть кода в отдельный модуль.
[https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.10.php#:~:text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5%20Python%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82,%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F.](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.10.php#:%7E:text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5%20Python%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82,%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F.)

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

если рассматривать PyCharm, то там код сворачивается при нажатии:

> ctrl + .

(контрол + точка). Разворачивается так же.